# Proving linear independence of linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the set of functions $f_c(x)$ with the following definitions is linearly independent in $V$, where $V$ is the set of all functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$

$f_c(x) = 0$ if $x \leq c$

$f_c(x) = x - c$ if $x \gt c$

I tried to prove it by proving that $0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i f_{c_i}(x)$, where $c_i$ is ordered with $c_i < c_{i+1}$ for all $i \in \Bbb N$, implies that $a_i = 0$ for all $i \in \Bbb N$.

first divided it into three cases, and showed that we only need to consider one. For the case where $x \leq c_1$, both sides are just $0$, so we can't use it to prove. The case where $c_1 \lt x \leq c_n$ and the case where $c_n \lt x$ can both be expressed by $0 = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i (x - c_i)$, where $k \lt n$ in the first case and $k = n$ in the second case. However after doing this I don't know how to continue. I tried to break the summation into terms and factor out the x, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You were on the right track.  Work by induction on $k$ and you only need to knock out one coefficient.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that you only need to consider *finite* linear combinations.  Work by induction on $n$ and note that if $n=1$, then $\forall c_1 \in \Bbb R~(\alpha_1 f_{c_1}=0 \Rightarrow \alpha_1=0)$ trivially.  That starts the induction.

Now assume we know the result for all linear combinations of length $\leq n$ and assume also that $g(x)=\overset{n+1}{\underset{k=1}\sum} \alpha_k f_{c_k}(x)=0$, the zero function.  Without loss of generality, the $c_k$ are in increasing order.  Consider $t$ such that $c_1 \lt t \lt c_2$.  Then $g(t)=0 \Rightarrow \alpha_1 f_{c_1}(t)=0 \Rightarrow \alpha_1=0$.

But now we can use our induction hypothesis to conclude $\forall k \in \{2, \ldots, n+1 \}~(\alpha_k=0)$.  Since $g(x)$ was an arbitrary linear combination of $n+1$ elements of our set resulting in $0$, we have completed the inductive step and we are done.